# console.log with standalone V8 (d8)

Tags: v8

The standalone V8 shell (`d8`) does not come with a `console` object, so I cannot do `console.log`. How do I print stuff to stdout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `print` function instead of `console.log`. For instance:

```
$ cat test.js
print('foo');
$ ~/src/v8/out/native/d8 test.js
foo
```

Head over to [Sandeep Datta's blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20161122024328/sandeepdatta.com/2011/10/using-v8-javascript-shell-d8.html) for more info on `d8` helper functions like `print`.

Comment: The link is dead.